# Powershell unzipping feature - strange behaviour

Tags: powershell, unzip, zip

I try to set up an installation script which sets up a development environment on a newly set up Windows 7 64 bit system.
So far I can't rely on third party tools like 7zip as the new user may not have the rights to install software on its first day.

Usually it is not a big deal, I have scripts who unzip files. But yesterday I stumbled across a computer which don't "want" to unzip my files.
Here is a short test script which I wrote to narrow down the problem:

```
$shell=new-object -com shell.application

$curLoc=get-location
write-host "Current Location is $($curLoc)"

$curPath=$curLoc.path
write-host "Current Path is $($curPath)"

$dest=$shell.namespace($curPath)
write-host "Destination-Object is $($dest)"

$zipFiles = get-childitem *.zip
write-host "zipfiles found:"
write-host $zipFiles

foreach ($singleZipFile in $zipFiles)
{
  write-host "Unzipping zipfile $($singleZipFile.fullname)"

  $zipFolder = $shell.namespace($singleZipFile.fullname)
  write-host "ZipFolder:"
  write-host $zipFolder  

  $dest.Copyhere($zipFolder.items())
  write-host "Unzipping zipfile $($singleZipFile.fullname) done"
}
```

On my test computer it runs without a problem:

```
PS F:\testcenter> .\unzip4.ps1
Current Location is F:\testcenter
Current Path is F:\testcenter
Destination-Object is System.__ComObject
zipfiles found:
F:\testcenter\test.zip
Unzipping zipfile F:\testcenter\test.zip
ZipFolder:
System.__ComObject
Unzipping zipfile F:\testcenter\test.zip done
PS F:\testcenter>
```

But on the problematic pc if fails as expected:

```
PS F:\testcenter> .\unzip4.ps1
Current Location is F:\testcenter
Current Path is F:\testcenter
Destination-Object is System.__ComObject
zipfiles found:
F:\testcenter\test.zip
Unzipping zipfile F:\testcenter\test.zip
Exception calling "NameSpace" with "1" argument(s): "Unknown Error (Except
ion from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))"
At F:\testcenter\unzip4.ps1:20 char:32
+   $zipFolder = $shell.namespace <<<< ($singleZipFile.fullname)
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

ZipFolder:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At F:\testcenter\unzip4.ps1:24 char:34
+   $dest.Copyhere($zipFolder.items <<<< ())
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (items:String) [], RuntimeExce
   ption
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Unzipping zipfile F:\testcenter\test.zip done
PS F:\testcenter>
```

Even if I force the usage of certain PS versions the problem stays the same...

Obviously the problem is passing the zipfile path and name as parameter to .namespace.
But why? And what can I do about it?
First I thought it is a problem concerning rights and tested it on a computer where I do not have admin right. But no error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on the cause of the failure, but if the computers you work with reliably have .Net 4.5 you could use the below change of the script to use that instead of the COM objects. Alternatively, check out the source where I found the .Net method in over in the [Powershell Script Repository.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Function-to-727d6200)

(Some of the variables are probably now redundant due to the fact there aren't any COM objects any more. Tweak output and variables to suit.)

```
# Load .Net 4.5 Compression File System, suppress output.
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem") | Out-Null 

$curLoc=get-location
write-host "Current Location is $($curLoc)"

$curPath=$curLoc.path
write-host "Current Path is $($curPath)"

$dest = $curPath
write-host "Destination-Object is $($dest)"

$zipFiles = get-childitem *.zip
write-host "Zipfiles found:"
write-host $zipFiles

foreach ($singleZipFile in $zipFiles)
{
  write-host "Unzipping zipfile $singleZipFile"

  $zipFolder = $singleZipFile
  write-host "ZipFolder:"
  write-host $zipFolder  
#Call .Net 4.5 Zip Extraction
  [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$singleZipFile", "$Dest")
  write-host "Unzipping zipfile $singleZipFile done"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't work either. Currently I am using self extracting archive files instead...

Comment: Interesting. What kind of error are you seeing with the .Net method? Is it similar to the other error?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the comment. It is pretty much the same error... I guess it is a somehow buggy Windows Installation/configuration.